# Automatically close ngDialog

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

To automatically close a `ngDialog` after the successful login, I used the below approach.

HTML template,

```
<a href="" ng-click="signin()">Log In</a>
<a href="" id="btnClose" ng-click="closeThisDialog()"   
style="display:none;">Close</a>
```

In the controller, the `signin` method has the following code to trigger the click event of close button,

```
$timeout(function () {
    var btnClose = document.getElementById('btnClose');
    angular.element(btnClose).triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);
```

Is there any better approach to close the `ngDialog` automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use [closeThisDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#scopeclosethisdialogvalue) just like below in your signin method. This will close the dialog after click the log in button.

```
$scope.signin = function() {
     $scope.closeThisDialog();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a little directive for this kind of stuff:

```
app.directive('closeDialog', function(ngDialog, $timeout) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if(attrs.closeDialog) {
        $timeout(function(){ngDialog.close()}, attrs.closeDialog * 1000);
      }
      element.bind('click', function(element) {
        ngDialog.close();
      })
    }
  }
});
```

You can use it by simple add the directive in your custom closing tag:

```
<button close-dialog="5">Close</button>
```

This dialog will close after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
// inside dialog's controller
function sigin() {
// do sigin
    .then(function () {
        that.closeThisDialog();
    })

}

// Page's controller 
var dialog = ngDialog.open({
   template  : 'scripts/modals/signup.tpl.html',
   ...
   etc.
});
```

Comment: what is 'that' in signin then ?